# Usage of と at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm having trouble translating this sentence from a manga. 
A guy who's already dead is talking to another.
He says:
私を殺したあの時と

And then the next page, it's only this speech bubble:
何一つ

I would have translated it as "You said you'd kill me that day" - "but you haven't killed anything at all" (from the context of the story).
But could the first sentence not also mean "When you killed me that day"? I don't really understand the meaning of と at the end. Is it for quotation or as when/if-indication (then と would be in the middle of the sentence).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 16):

> 「[私]{わたし}を[殺]{ころ}したあの[時]{とき}と（、）[何一]{なにひと}つ・・・」

To understand this, you need to have many natural expressions on your active vocabulary so that you can fill in what is missing or left unsaid.  Japanese is NOT a language where saying everything is beautiful.

The only possible phrase that is left unsaid following [私]{わたし}を[殺]{ころ}したあの[時]{とき}と[何一]{なにひと}つ would be 「[変]{か}わっていない」 = "***has not changed***".

「何一つ」 is always followd by a negative expression such as できない、[知]{し}らない、[言]{い}っていない、[考]{かんが}えていない、[持]{も}っていない, etc.

In this case, it would need to be 変わっていない from the context and if I may surprise you, especially from the particle 「と」.　「～～**と**変わっていない」、「～～**と**変わらない」、「～～**と**何一つ変わらない」, etc. would need to be remembered because these phrases will keep appearing (or keep getting left unsaid!).

This 「と」 is used to describe the standard for comparison and for that reason, one could also say 「～～**と**[同]{おな}じ」 = "same ***as*** ~~".

"***Nothing (whatsoever) has changed from that time/day when you killed me***."

Answer (score -2):

Oftentimes, sentences ending in to と思います etc can have the portion after the と clipped and left unsaid. Is it possible that is what is happening in this situation?