# What is this usage of と at the end of a sentence in this song? And in general?

Tags: particle-と, song-lyrics, anastrophe

In the song Chercher by KOTOKO, there are a couple lines that look like completed thoughts/sentences, but end in と

For example

> 約束｛やくそく｝する　私｛わたし｝がすぐあなたのこと探｛さが｝し出｛だ｝すと

Also she definitely says 「と」and not 「よ」

I read [Usage of と at the end of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/usage-of-%e3%81%a8-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) but am still unsure what the と implies. Is it like a particle from a dialect or is there more implied to the sentence?

手伝ってください！　ありがとうございます

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to rearrange it into a more standard word order?

> 私{わたし}がすぐあなたのこと探{さが}し出{だ}すと**約束{やくそく}する**

This と is just the standard quotative particle associated with 約束する.

In the lyrics she just said 約束する first and followed that with the content of the promise.