# Difficulty understanding と at sentence end

Tags: sentence-final-particles

From an interview.

Question: カルチャーショックって、たくさんありましたよね？

Answer: 多分 たくさんあったけど、もう だいぶ なれちゃったのと、 日本と違いすぎて、なんかカルチャーショックにも 思えないぐらいだなっていう感じ。

What is the role of 「と」 after なれちゃったの?

Link to source: https://youtu.be/jtlqYTMa3oY?t=358.

Also later in the same video: https://youtu.be/jtlqYTMa3oY?t=429 in another context (「で、主張は、日本人に比べたら、やっぱり する人が多いと思うのと、あとは、すごく優しい人が 多いですね。」).

I found several questions on this topic, but I couldn't find one that fits this case:

- [と at the end of the sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83252/%e3%81%a8-at-the-end-of-the-sentence)
- [Usage of と at the end of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/usage-of-%e3%81%a8-at-the-end-of-a-sentence?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95617/45489

Comment: It's not at the sentence end. It's just an "and" と that connects to the next phrase.

Comment: Yes, both comments answer my question. Could you please either mark it as a duplicate, or move your comment to an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Marked as duplicate :) Thanks for finding the near-identical question!